# How to define an Array of values (or a Column) into a Procedure Argument?

Tags: stored-procedures, netezza

I am working on a Netezza SP and is stuck with a problem.

I have a SP, defined as say:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_PROC(VARCHAR(ANY)) RETURNS INTEGER LANGUAGE NZPLSQL
AS
    BEGIN_PROC
    DECLARE 
        v_temp ALIAS FOR $1; 
        /* Other decalarations */
        result_ts INTEGER; 
BEGIN 
        result_ts := 0;
/* Procedure Body */
RETURN result_ts; 
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN 
RAISE NOTICE 'Exception Raised: %', SQLERRM; 
END; 
END_PROC;
```

If I am running this SP with one value, such as:

```
SELECT MY_PROC('TEST_INPUT');
```

But if I am trying to run it with a column value, such as:

```
SELECT MY_PROC(TEST_COLUMN) FROM TEST_TABLE;
```

Its giving me error as:
*`ERROR:  Can't use a stored procedure in this context`*

I know that in the second scenario I am passing an Array (i guess) but this is not what the Procedure has expected.

Now I am trying to have a procedure that can accept these kind of values but could not succeeded so far, LOOPing and all I have taken care but only problem is the Argument which I don't know how to pass.

Any help would be appreciated, let me know if I need to provide any extra info on this.

Asif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stored procedures in Netezza, as of v7.2, can only be called in the following ways, as [documented here.](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/%23!/SSULQD_7.2.0/com.ibm.nz.sproc.doc/c_sproc_how_to_execute.html?cp=SSULQD_7.2.0)

```
CALL sproc_name(...);
EXEC sproc_name(...);
SELECT sproc_name(...);
```

Note that the SELECT form does not allow a FROM clause.

If you want the stored procedure to act on a particular column from a particular table that changes from invocation to invocation, you could pass the names of those as arguments to the stored procedure and have the entirety of the SQL logic encoded within.  You could even pass arbitrary code into the stored procedure to build a query internally.

The way you are trying to call it now is more like calling a user defined function, and that simply won't work with stored procedures here.

Comment: Yep. . agree with you. . :)